# How to add Data sanity logic in airflow

Tags: validation, airflow

I am implemented airflow , can we add data sanity logic. suppose I have Task1 which do the following task

```
1.Read the data from the data source--RAW DATA.
2. do join with dimensional table to get the some relation detail product name etc.
3. Store output file some location after step 2.
```

There is a task2 that stored the output file into database. but before task2 execution i need to some data validation like count of RAW DATA should equal to the store output file count i.e after joining
like count(raw_data) = count(raw_data_join_with_dimensional) , if it is true then trigger the Task2 else send the alert and failed the job.

Answer (score 3):

For that use case a possible workflow could be:

```
check_op = SQLCheckOperator(
    task_id='check_task',
    sql='YOUR VALIDATION SQL',
    conn_id='YOUR CONN',
)

t2_op = YourNextOperator()

failure_op = EmailOperator(subject='check has failed', to='YOUR EMAIL', trigger_rule='one_failed')

check_op >> [t2_op, failure_op]
```

It works as follows:

1. `SQLCheckOperator` runs the query against the DB. If query returns `False` the check has failed thus the operator will be in `Failure` state. If the query returns value the query consider as success thus the operator will be in `Success` state.
2. EmailOperator will be triggered if `SQLCheckOperator` status is failure otherwise `YourNextOperator` will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Go see @Elad's answer, there's a much more specific operator for this task.

The [`airflow.sensors.sql_sensor.SqlSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/sql_sensor.html) can be used to build a task that can check data quality:

```py
from airflow.sensors import sql_sensor


...

check_data_task = sql_sensor.SqlSensor(
  task_id="check_data",
  conn_id="YourConnectionIdentifier",
  sql="SELECT CASE WHEN data_is_valid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ...",
  timeout=0
)
```

The key being that your `sql` argument return "at least one cell that contains a non-zero / empty string value" -- according to the documentation. The `timeout=0` means that it will check once and fail if your data check query doesn't "pass"

Comment: SqlSensor is used to wait until criteria is met. It's good for uses cases when you are waiting for another process to finish. This doesn't seem to be the use case in the question. His process creates the output and he wishes to validate that the last step finished and the data is accurate.

Comment: Correct. And you can set the retries to zero (nb: that's the default) and have it fail when the criteria is not met, and continue when it is? Was I unclear in some portion?

Comment: yes that will work but you have a straight forward way to do that using the
[SQLCheckOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4e8f9cc8d02b29c325b8a5a76b4837671bdf5f68/airflow/operators/sql.py#L41)

Comment: ‍♂️ leave it to Airflow to duplicate code for the same goal.